# Select data when at least half of the records are evaluated for 'Y'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
evaluation([id_member, id_article], opinion)
```

I tried to select id_article while at least half of members have set opinion for 'Y'.

For example :

```
(1, 1, NULL)
(2, 1, NULL)
(1, 2, NULL)
(2, 2, 'Y')
```

The query should select article 2 (for the second article) since one of the two rows contains a 'Y'.

I can't find how to do it!

`[]` means that `id_member` and `id_article` make up the primary key.

Comment: Is the `opinion` column a `NUMBER` or a `VARCHAR2`?  Your sample data is numeric, the text of your question talks about a one character string (either `Y` or `N`), and the subject of your question talks about a multiple character string like `Yes`.  Which of the three is correct?

Comment: I've seen my code now. `opinion` is `Y` or `NULL`

Comment: OK.  So then can you update your sample data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if opinion is string:

```
SELECT id_article
FROM
Evaluation
GROUP BY id_article
HAVING
AVG(CASE OPINION WHEN 'Y' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) >= 0.5
```

if opinion is decimal (assuming 0.0 or 1.0) then

```
SELECT id_article
FROM
Evaluation
GROUP BY id_article
HAVING
AVG(Opinion) >= 0.5
```

if opinion is integer (assuming 0 or 1) then

```
SELECT id_article
FROM
Evaluation
GROUP BY id_article
HAVING
AVG(Opinion*10) >= 5
```

Comment: Just one more question: can I use `AND id_article IN` other SELECT? Sorry, I don't have a dbms to test.

Comment: No, you will have to do that in a where clause...

after the table name and before the group by clause then write
WHERE
id_article IN (SELECT .....)

However in most cases I would recommend using the
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE sometable.id_Article = Evaluation.id_Article)

Comment: I belive that should work yes...however that NATURAL JOIN was actually a new thing to me :)

However that last closing paranthese ")" is one to many....if my eyes is not mistaken and im to tired...

Answer (score 0):

this is the perfect opportunity to use a having clause.

```
select blah, blah, blah
from evaluation join other tables as required
where whatever
having (sum(opinion) / count(*)) * 100 > 50
```

Comment: Where is `group by`?  Fraction is inverted.

Comment: Same question @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: You cannot SUM a string. You can count it, though. `COUNT(opinion) * 100 / COUNT(*)` should do, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method for efficiently getting the entire row using the under-appreciated ratio_to_report() analytic function:

```
select
  id_member,
  id_article,
  opinion
from   
  (select id_member,
          id_article,
          opinion,
          ratio_to_report(case when opinion 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
            over (partition by id_article) rtr
   from   evaluation)
where
  rtr >= 0.5;
```